# Using SSJS to dynamically build landing page content

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, landing-page, microsites

How would this (or does this) translate to SSJS? This would be part of the HTML body of a landing page.

```
%%[IF @var > 1 THEN]%%
Show this content
%%[ELSE]%%
Show that content
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var var1 = Variable.GetValue("@var");  // or whatever

if (var1 > 1) {
  Write("Show this content");
} else {
  Write("Show that content");
}
</script>
```

I have an [example here](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8) that shows a mixture of AMPScript and SSJS.

Also this official documentation is helpful: [Server-Side JavaScript](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/)